# Capability to handle growing text without use of flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I am following MSDN document's look and feel to display text inside a box which has the capability of expanding and shrinking . I have achieved this using flex and have not given any fixed widths to any divs.

Below is a simple working solution . Here the innermost texts inside body can grow/shrink and the parent divs adjust accordingly. Similar to Text1,Text2 I can dynamically have Text3,Text4 etc . The image and first text are in line and subsequent texts will be placed one below the other and this behaviour is dynamic

Since the usage of flex is not supported in older versions of IE , how can I achieve the same thing using older style of css? I am not able to achieve a)Handle growing text b)Handle number of Text items(Text1,Text2,Text3) without using flex as I dont want to fix the width of divs
c)Solution should be responsive

**Working solution**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div style="padding:19px 21px 17px;border:solid 1px #b3a188;background-color:#fff;">
  <span style="display:block;margin 0 244px 19px 0;font-family:Arial;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-heightnormal;letter-spacing:normal;color:#b3a188;">Header1</span>
  <div style="display:flex;flex-flow:row nowrap;flex:1 0 auto;width:100%">
    <div style="background-color:#1175b5;border:1px solid #1175b5;border-left-width:2px;border-right-width:2px"></div>

    <div style="background-color:rgba(17,117,181,0.06);padding:16px 25px 20px;display:flex;flex:1;width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;justify-content:space-evenly;">
      <img src="test1.png" style="width:16px;height:16px;margin-right:12px;">

      <div style="display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;flex:1 0 auto;box-sizing:border-box;
    word-break:break-word;width:95%;">
        <div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:normal;letter-spacing:normal;color:#231f20;width:100%;">
          Body1</div>
        <div style="margin :8px 0 8px 12px;font-family:Arial;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:1.43;
    letter-spacing:normal;color:#231f20;margin-left:0px;word-break:break-word;width:100%;">
          Random text to be displayed RandomRandom text to be displayed Random. This text can grow randomly
        </div>

        <div style="margin :8px 0 8px 12px;font-family:Arial;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:1.43;
    letter-spacing:normal;color:#231f20;margin-left:0px;word-break:break-word;width:100%;">
          Second line of display . This text can also grow in size . Similarly the parent divs should have the capability of expanding and shrinking according;y
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: "*Here the innermost texts inside body can grow/shrink and the parent divs adjust accordingly. Similar to Text1,Text2 I can dynamically have Text3,Text4 etc*" This is the default behavior of HTML and CSS, not anything special to the Flexible Box model. It's unclear what you're asking for since completely unstyled divs will give you the same behavior.

Comment: @TylerH : I have used flex to align the image and text side by side and subsequent texts to flow vertically below it and also responsive making sure the text doesnt go out of div. I wanted to know if this can be achieved without flex.

Comment: You can achieve the same thing with display: inline-block (and, btw, just use border-left on the div that you want to have a blue left border on... no need for an entirely separate div; I believe Salketer's answer illustrates that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flex parts were not really needed at all... There was no use for them. The only thing that was using the flexbox feature was an empty div to create a border on the left of the section. I added the border directly instead.

```html
<div style="padding:19px 21px 17px;border:solid 1px #b3a188;background-color:#fff;">
  <span style="display:block;margin 0 244px 19px 0;font-family:Arial;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-heightnormal;letter-spacing:normal;color:#b3a188;">Header1</span>
  <div style="width:100%;border:1px solid #1175b5;border-width:0 0 0 4px;">

    <div style="background-color:rgba(17,117,181,0.06);padding:16px 25px 20px;width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;justify-content:space-evenly;">
      <img src="test1.png" style="width:16px;height:16px;margin-right:12px;">

      <div style="box-sizing:border-box;
    word-break:break-word;width:95%;">
        <div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:normal;letter-spacing:normal;color:#231f20;width:100%;">
          Body1</div>
        <div style="margin :8px 0 8px 12px;font-family:Arial;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:1.43;
    letter-spacing:normal;color:#231f20;margin-left:0px;word-break:break-word;width:100%;">
          Random text to be displayed RandomRandom text to be displayed Random. This text can grow randomly
        </div>

        <div style="margin :8px 0 8px 12px;font-family:Arial;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:1.43;
    letter-spacing:normal;color:#231f20;margin-left:0px;word-break:break-word;width:100%;">
          Second line of display . This text can also grow in size . Similarly the parent divs should have the capability of expanding and shrinking according;y
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , one thing if I make width:100% instead of width:95% in a div (<div style="box-sizing:border-box;
    word-break:break-word;width:95%;">)  , the text will go out of the box . Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I don't see it going out myself so can't really say...

Comment: @Salketer But this solution is not responsive . Op's solution has image and text side by side when opened in mobile. But the above solution has image and text one Below the other

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing this out, I was not aware of this reponsiveness requirement. As usual, use media queries to handle this?

Comment: @Salketer : Yes media queries is a good option.

Comment: @Salketer : Yes it needs to be responsive. Whatever works in IE

Answer (score -2):

Header1

```
<div style="background-color:rgba(17,117,181,0.06);padding:16px 25px 20px;display:flex;flex:1;width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;justify-content:space-evenly;">
  <img src="test1.png" style="width:16px;height:16px;margin-right:12px;">

  <div style="display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;flex:1 0 auto;box-sizing:border-box;
word-break:break-word;width:95%;">
    <div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:normal;letter-spacing:normal;color:#231f20;width:100%;">
      Body1</div>
    <div style="margin :8px 0 8px 12px;font-family:Arial;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;
font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:1.43;
letter-spacing:normal;color:#231f20;margin-left:0px;word-break:break-word;width:100%;">
      Random text to be displayed RandomRandom text to be displayed Random. This text can grow randomly
    </div>

    <div style="margin :8px 0 8px 12px;font-family:Arial;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;
font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:1.43;
letter-spacing:normal;color:#231f20;margin-left:0px;word-break:break-word;width:100%;">
      Second line of display . This text can also grow in size . Similarly the parent divs should have the capability of expanding and shrinking according;y
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't just dump a bunch of code that we need to mentally diff with what is in the question. Point out what you changed, and how it helps.

Comment: Your code is identical to code in [the first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74717271/2) of the original question.  That revision was posted on 2022-12-07 13:15:21Z, your answer was posted on 2022-12-07 13:16:16Z or roughly 1 minute later.  Why did you do this? - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/33361929).